# Is the use of "a" in the following context correct?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

> **A** question for Mormons. Would you support a polygamous relationship over a monogamous one?
>
> Question for Mormons. Would you support a polygamous relationship over a monogamous one?

Both of the sentences are very commonly used. Is there any difference between the two? Can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: What is the context? Is this the proposed title of an essay, a headline for a newspaper or blog? Neither is a complete sentence as written. More information, please. :-)

Comment: Are you sure that it's not "Questions for Mormons"?

Comment: @MickSharpe That's a typo.

Comment: @MarkHubbard provided more context.

Comment: I think that it's you who should be providing the context. It's your question.

Comment: @MickSharpe I have. Check the edit log.

Comment: Do mean using the article _a_ before _question_? I think you need to put _a_ before _question_ here. There's just one sense in which question can be uncountable and that's where you mean _doubt_ as in _call sth into question_. Ofcourse there are also some expressions that _question_ can be used without an article as in _without question_, or _good question_ but these are idiomatic expressions. Here actually you're proposing a question (an interrogative statement) so I think using an article is necessary. I haven't heard _question for someone_ as in your answer.

Comment: @Sadiq I need better glasses.

Comment: Only "A question for Mormons" is grammatically correct. "Question for Mormons" is idiomatic but I would avoid using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both work.  In both cases, you could think of the first sentence as being similar to a heading, title or subtitle.  That is especially true of the second version.